# Extracting data from a file with multi-line records,saving each range to a separate file

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like this

```
     *TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************5845
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:45:52
 05:46:26 GENAC 1 : ARQC
EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE: NO ARPC
 05:46:30 GENAC 2 : AAC
 01 FEB 2016     05:47:41      10160021

     WITHDRAW
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ?
INVALID TRANSCATION ON TERMINAL.
-----------------------
[020t 05:47:05 CARD TAKEN
[020t 05:47:07 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*742*02/01/2016*05:47*
     *TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************2584
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:47:27
 05:48:00 GENAC 1 : ARQC
 05:48:05 GENAC 2 : TC
[020t 05:48:16 CARD TAKEN
[020t 05:48:22 NOTES PRESENTED 0,0,2,0
 01 FEB 2016     05:48:52      10160021

     WITHDRAW
     FROM XXXXXXXX    ?
AMT   GHC40.00
[020t 05:48:31 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*743*02/01/2016*05:57*
     *TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************3862
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:57:28
 01 FEB 2016     05:58:33      10160021

     INQUIRY
     FROM XXXXXXXX90018
AVAIL          GHC1260.20  
LEDGER         GHC1260.20  
[020t 05:58:06 CARD TAKEN
[020t 05:58:11 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*744*02/01/2016*06:43*
     *TRANSACTION STARTED*
[020t CARD INSERTED
[020tCARD: *************1972
DATE 01-02-16    TIME 06:43:53
 01 FEB 2016     06:44:56      10160021
5029110111271972
4490    4490
     INQUIRY
     FROM XXXXXXXX23013
AVAIL          GHC14.28
LEDGER         GHC14.28
[020t 06:44:25 CARD TAKEN
[020t 06:44:29 TRANSACTION END
[0r(1)2[000p[040qe1w3h162[020t*745*02/01/2016*06:56*
```

and need to extract what is between `*TRANSACTION STARTED*` and `TRANSACTION END`, ignoring all other information, and create a new file for each range.
The new file will contain only

```
    [020t CARD INSERTED
    [020tCARD: *************2584
    DATE 01-02-16    TIME 05:47:27
     05:48:00 GENAC 1 : ARQC
     05:48:05 GENAC 2 : TC
    [020t 05:48:16 CARD TAKEN
    [020t 05:48:22 NOTES PRESENTED 0,0,2,0
     01 FEB 2016     05:48:52      10160021

         WITHDRAW
         FROM XXXXXXXX    ?
    AMT   GHC40.00
    [020t 05:48:31
```

I have done some modification on the previous but i get this Error:

```
Can't use string ("/home/lord-ivan/Soures_Code/Perl"...) as a SCALAR ref while "strict refs" in use at readfile.pl line 31, <$fh> line 1.
```

My new code

```
#! /usr/bin/perl/ 

use warnings;
use strict;

#file to open
my $somefile = "/home/lord-ivan/Soures_Code/Perl/projects/Data/EJDATA.LOG";

open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $somefile) or die "Could not open file '$somefile' $!"; 
print "$somefile open";

#Extract ranges of lines from a file

while (<$fh>) {

    if (/TRANSACTION STARTED/ .. /TRANSACTION END/) 
    {
         next if /TRANSACTION\s*(STARTED|END)/;
        print $_;   
    }
}


my $ofh;

my $outputfile = "/home/lord-ivan/Soures_Code/Perl/projects/EJ Transport/Queue/.txt";

BEGIN {$outputfile= "EJ"};

open ($fh, ">>${$outputfile}.txt", print $fh $_);

close($outputfile);
$outputfile++;
```

Why can't it work.

Answer (score 0):

@Iord-Ivan
**Try to study**

what is the datatype.?

File handling

What is handler.

Your `$somefile` store only the file name. Then you iterate the while loop using `$somefile`. But your `$somefile` contain only the file name not contain the file content.

You file content is stored into the `$fh` handler so iterate the while loop for $fh handler. Then check it line by line.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $somefile = "input.txt";
open (my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $somefile) or die "Could not open file '$somefile' $!"; 
print "$somefile open";
while (<$fh>) {

    if (/TRANSACTION STARTED/ .. /TRANSACTION END/) 
    {
         next if /TRANSACTION\s*(STARTED|END)/;
        print $_;   
    }
}
```

After studying perl, finish the balance program(FILE WRITE). :)